# How do I construct this snippet to store both date and time for column "publicationDate" in MySQL also adding another column "editedDate" to be added?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysql-workbench

```
  public function storeFormValues( $params ) {

// Store all the parameters
$this->__construct( $params );

// Parse and store the publication date
if ( isset($params['publicationDate']) ) {
  $publicationDate = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate'] );

  if ( count($publicationDate) == 3 ) {
    list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $publicationDate;
    $this->publicationDate = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
  }
 }
}
```

Both columns are being stored via hidden input fields being that they cannot be set via form by user. The default value for "editedDate" is null unless the page/article is being updated as in which it will constantly change per every edit. The case for "publicationDate" is set once. The problem I'm having is the date isn't being stored even though the correct values is being set through the form (0000-00-00 00:00:00). The "publicationDate" column stores only the date with the time value being - 00:00:00 (example 2019-12-05 00:00:00) and when storing the edited date it stores all date & time values but wrong date & time being submitted to the database even though the form is submitting the correct values.

**This how it's being inserted into the database**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO examples ( publicationDate, editedDate, title, summary, content, imageExtension ) VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate), FROM_UNIXTIME(:editedDate), :example1, :example2, :example3 )";
```

**In the html form the input "values" are echoed**

```
echo date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
```

When viewing the source code in the browser the "values" are being set even the empty value for "editedDate" when it is the first time the page is created/published (publicationDate) which can be null in the database.

**I finally fixed it with a bit of trial and errors. First, in the form template only the input for "publicationDate" is sent to the browser (*hidden) with the value being echoed if the webpage/article is just being created (new) & if it's being edited only the input for "editedDate" is being sent to the browser. But then I had to change the snippet I knew was causing the values inputted in the form not being put in the database

```
    if ( isset($params['publicationDate'])) {
    $this->publicationDate = time ( );
    $this->editedDate = time ("");
    }
     else if (isset($params['editedDate'])) {
      $this->editedDate = time( );
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code related to storing the Editing timestamp, so I can't really comment on that. As for the publish date/time, look at this line:

```
$this->publicationDate = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
```

The php documentation here ([php.net mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)) shows that the parameters to mtkime are Hour, minute, seconds, month, day, year. So, from your code, `mtkime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y)` you are not attempting to store anything other than 00:00:00 for the time portion.

Have you considered altering the mysql column for pulbishingdate to have a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and writing a trigger for before update to set the editing time to now()?

If this doesn't help you solve the problem, try to share the form structure and possibly a dump of $_POST to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

From one side, we have the publicationDate, the easiest way to store this, is setting the DB to autofill it with `CurrentTimeStamp()` fuction, as long as you just want to store it with any further changes. It will store it just once, and by it default value (current time) if you do not specify it on the INSERT query.

On the other side, editDate, you can easily get it from the MySQL server with `now()` without the using of forms.

**PHP**

```
function your_edit_funcion() {
    [...];
    $qry = "UPDATE table SET [...], editDate = NOW()";
    [...]
}
```

Comment: CurrentTimestamp() function is a no go. I can set it to TIMESTAMP() only. I am using MySQL Workbench to work with/create database(s)/table(s). I've messed around this function as well as the as well as the original setup with default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to no avail.